# Is the collect function of Flow a block function in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, android-room, kotlin-flow

I hope to delete records by Id list and relative files with Room.

I find the files can be deleted and the records can't be deleted when I run Code A

I find the records can be deleted when I run Code B.

It seems that `Log.e("My","Fire")` is not launched in Code A. I don't know why?

**Q1:** What's wrong with Code A ?

**Q2:** Is the `collect` a block function when I use Flow?

**Q3:**  Is `fun getByID(id:Int): Flow<RecordEntity?>`  good design? maybe it should be `fun getByID(id:Int): RecordEntity?` .

**Code A**

```
class RecordRepository @Inject constructor(
    private val mRecordDao:RecordDao
) {   
    override fun getByID(id:Int): Flow<MRecord?> =  mRecordDao.getByID(id).map {it?.let{ModelMapper.entityToModel(it) } }
 

    override suspend fun deleteRecord(idList: List<Int>) = withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
        idList.forEach{
            getByID(it).collect {
               it?.let {
                   val filename = it.soundFileName
                   deleteFileOrFolder(filename)
               }
            }
        }
        Log.e("My","Fire")
        mRecordDao.deleteRecord(idList)
    }

}

@Dao
interface  RecordDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM record_table where id=:id")
    fun getByID(id:Int): Flow<RecordEntity?> 

    @Query("delete from record_table where id in (:idList)")
    suspend fun deleteRecord(idList: List<Int>)
}
```

**Code B**

```
class RecordRepository @Inject constructor(
    private val mRecordDao:RecordDao
) {   
    override fun getByID(id:Int): Flow<MRecord?> =  mRecordDao.getByID(id).map {it?.let{ModelMapper.entityToModel(it) } }


    override suspend fun deleteRecord(idList: List<Int>) = withContext(Dispatchers.Default) { 
        mRecordDao.deleteRecord(idList)
    }

}

//The same
```

**Added Content:**

To Arpit Shukla: Thanks!

I find many query samples to return Flow data with Room using Code C.

I think Code D is enought and it's simple

I'm confused why I need to use Flow in Room, you know I only want the entities once  mostly, could you tell me?

**Code C**

```
@Dao
interface  RecordDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM record_table ORDER BY createdDate desc")
    fun listRecord():  Flow<List<RecordEntity>>
}
```

**Code D**

```
@Dao
interface  RecordDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM record_table ORDER BY createdDate desc")
    suspend  fun listRecord(): List<RecordEntity>
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`collect` function suspends forever. It never resumes. So any code you put after `collect` will never be executed. This is the problem with Code A.

If you want to make code A work, you should collect each flow in a separate coroutine using the `launch` function.

```kotlin
override suspend fun deleteRecord(idList: List<Int>) = withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
    idList.forEach {
       launch {
           getByID(it).collect {
               it?.soundFileName?.let { deleteFileOrFolder(it) }
           }
       }
    }
    Log.e("My","Fire")
    mRecordDao.deleteRecord(idList)
}
```

Also, you need not switch Dispatchers in the code, Room does that automatically.

**Edit:** If you need to get the list of `RecordEntity` only once, code D is a better approach. `Flow` is required when we need to observe the changes in the query result. For example, while displaying a list of `RecordEntity` in the UI,  we would want to update the UI if the data in database changes and for that we can return `Flow` from Dao.

For your particular case, you can do this:

```kotlin
@Dao
interface  RecordDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM record_table where id=:id")
    suspend fun getByID(id:Int): RecordEntity?
}

override suspend fun deleteRecord(idList: List<Int>) {
    idList.forEach { id ->
        getByID(id)?.soundFileName?.let { deleteFileOrFolder(it) }
    }
    Log.e("My","Fire")
    mRecordDao.deleteRecord(idList)
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But your code maybe cause problem, maybe  `mRecordDao.deleteRecord(idList)` is launched first, and `getByID(it)` will return null.

Comment: Do you have any special reason for returning `Flow<RecordEntity?>` instead of just `RecordEntity` from `getById` function of `RecordDao`. If you only want the entity once, you don't need a flow there. And this will simplify the code.

Comment: Thanks! Would you please to see my added content in the question?

Comment: I have edited the answer. See if it solves your problem